# Is there any way to combine a picture's border into the shape in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon

I made an icon with a border, but I don't want the border. If I remove the border, the icon loses it's thickness and doesn't look right. Is there any way to make the border into part of the shape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off-hand...

Select all, Object > Expand Appearance (if available) 
then Object > Expand, 
then Pathfinder > Unite.

Without seeing the icon, this is the best I can offer.